# i want to access an arraylist of one activity to another(Without using intent) but getting classcastException

Tags: android, arraylist, classcastexception

I want to access an arrayList from one activity to another,I have tried as below,But it gives me ClassCast exception,
**logcat**

```
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eps.blancatours/com.eps.blancatours.ui.AddBookingpopupActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.eps.blancatours.ui.DestinationsActivity
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.eps.blancatours.ui.DestinationsActivity
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at com.eps.blancatours.ui.AddBookingpopupActivity.onCreate(AddBookingpopupActivity.java:30)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
08-02 11:33:37.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
```

**destinationActivity.java**

```
 public class MyApp extends Application {
        public ArrayList<String> getState() {
            return names;
        }

        public void setState(ArrayList<String> s) {
            names = s;
        }
    }
```

**secondactivity.java**

```
   MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
          dest = appState.getState();
```

Comment: Show Logcat output. and may be your issue is with `DestinationsActivity appState = ((DestinationsActivity) getApplicationContext());`

Comment: this may help you http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/10/28/pass-arraylist-activity-android/

Comment: @GiruBhai-I know it can possible with intent easily,but thing is i am not going one acitivy to another,get my point?i just want to access its arrayList available to all other activities

Answer (score 1):

Error Clearly mentioned in Logcat which is

**`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.eps.blancatours.ui.DestinationsActivity`**

it mean that you are Cast `getApplicationContext()` to an Activity which is not possible.

and as you wanted to use a same ArrayList to all the Activities in your application you need to declare that ArrayList in your `Application class`

Declare this code in `Application class` instead of `destinationActivity.java`.

```
public ArrayList<String> names;

names = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> getState() {
    return names;
}

public void setState(ArrayList<String> s) {
    names = s;
}
```

While to use this ArrayList in anyother Activity you need to use following code.

```
MyApplicationClass applicaionClass = (MyApplicationClass) getApplication();

ArrayList<String> mStateNames = (ArrayList<String>) applicaionClass.getState();
```

Comment: Please see my quation title sir..I dont want to "pass" it..I just want to make it available to all other activities...got?

Answer (score 0):

Because `getApplicationContext()` will return an Application object, not an Activity.

Also, there's no point in `dest = new ArrayList<String>()` if you're immediately going to overwrite it.

Comment: @user3820044 recommended solution is to use  intent as given in this link http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/10/28/pass-arraylist-activity-android/

Answer (score 0):

You cant cast your `getApplicationContext` to the first activity it will simply return the reference of the applications' context not your `destinationActivity` thus giving you `ClassCast exception`.

Instead you can pass the arraylist through intent where you start the `secondactivity`

Comment: I just want to use one activity's arrayList to another activity without use of intent.

Comment: @user3820044 you can make it static which is a really bad idea, or you can use Intent to pass an arraylist to the second activity

Comment: Static isn't necessarily bad.  Static data inside an activity is a bit smelly, but it isn't uncommon for a data structure used by multiple activities to be held as a singleton.

Comment: @GabeSechan it is also a security flaw for using a static arraylist.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin No its not.  Not just for having a static variable.  It could be part of one somehow, but a variable being static is not in and of itself a security flaw.

Comment: @GabeSechan but there is a chance an attacker can get on that object.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin There's a chance they can get at a non-static object too.  I'm not saying there aren't ways to misuse statics, but merely being static is not a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

I have declared my arrayList as a global variable in my Constant class and declared it as a staic,My code is as below;

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dest = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

**use**

```
dest = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        dest = Const.dest;
```